# Sphinx RT index makes MySQL server go away

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have an Sphinx RT index which I update on regular intervals. Now I have a document with 500.000 words, making the update script throw the `MySQL server has gone away (error code: 2006, State: HY000)` error.

I have already updated/checked the relevant MySQL settings, which are:

```
wait_timeout = 28800
max_allowed_packet = 1G
```

What could still be causing this problem? The RT-index `mem_limit` is set to `128M`

Comment: Does `searchd` crash when you try to insert that document?

Comment: Not sure, how should I check it, asuming that there is no logging of a crash?

Comment: crashes are usually logged to `searchd.log`. Note when using sphinxQL, you are NOT actully talking to a mysql server, talking direct to searchd, so the mysql server settings are not relevent nor involved. (its just the MySQL Client, doesn't expect to be talking to anything other than mysql server, so calls it 'MySQL server' erroneously in this case) - sphinx does have its own similar setting http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-max-packet-size

Comment: Alright, I will raise the max_packet_size to the mem_limit size within sphinx config? The searchd log shows no logs of crashes, but: `WARNING: failed to receive MySQL request body (client=127.0.0.1:55514(5), exp=16217725, error='Success')`

Comment: Great, I have updated the `max_packet_size` of `Sphinx` itself and now the document is loaded fine. I have set the `max_packet_size` to `256M`.

Comment: `max_packet_size` in Sphinx 3.3.1 cannot be bigger than 128M. I fixed the problem by adding `batch_size: 500` (default is 1000)